# Issue with node-sass in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, node-modules, angular-calendar

I'm facing following issue on MAC while running existing Angular4 Application. It shows me this error on executing `ng serve`

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/angular-calendar-week-hours-view/angular-calendar-week-hours-view.scss
>   Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Im importing style in angular-cli.json as follows

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/angular-calendar-week-hours-view/angular-calendar-week-hours-view.scss"
      ],
```

What could be the probable issue?

```
"styleExt": "scss",
```

Added styleExt as scss in angular-cli.json.
I do have node 9.11.1

Comment: did you run `npm install` beforehand ? Are you running `ng serve` or `npm run start`, which launches `ng serve` ?

Comment: I ran npm install, that did not worked. Then I did three more ways, sudo npm i node-sass, sudo npm install node-sass

Comment: Try rebuilding node-saas.   
npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass done. same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue with latest node.js version. Issue resolved with installation of older version 6.8.0

Latest version is throwing error to `npm install node-sass`
It works good in lower version.

Comment: there has to be another way of achieving it, without going 2.* versions back